# Remove IntelliJ Project Version Control

Tags: intellij-idea

How do I remove all version control associated with a project in IntelliJ?

Comment: Actually I ended up re-enabling it.  Works Great.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

Go to Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Version Control | **Directory Mappings**, select the mapping(s), click `[-]` icon or press <kbd>Delete</kbd> to remove the mapping or change the association to `None`.

Comment: Still the `CVS` dir is there inside each dir ! Any way to delete all of those ?

Comment: Doesn't work. Moves it downward, doesn't remove it.

Comment: in the newer Idea, it's _Directory Mappings_

Answer (score 19):

Alternatively, you can delete the **vcs.xml** which exist under the **.idea** folder;

```
.idea/vcs.xml
```

Answer (score 7):

Just to add to the answers above. For one of my projects I had not only VCS (git) enabled, but also connected it to a remote repository. To start from a clean slate you can,

1. Go to `File` | `Settings` | `Version Control` and click `-`. This will disable the VCS and list it under `Unregistered roots:`
2. If you really want to get rid of that `Unregistered roots:` entry and all of the tracking information, go to your project folder and delete the `..\projectDir\.git\` folder also (provided that your were using git as your vcs)

Answer (score 4):

For me VCS totally removed this way:

"You could disable all VCS-related plugins in Settings: File | Settings | Plugins."

(answer from this page: https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000709890-Turn-off-vcs-integration-by-default)

Answer (score 2):

VCS -> Git -> Remotes... and opened Git remotes window. Then you can delete, edit or add the remote connection what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the vcs in Intellij Project Follow this steps -

1. Open Setting or Press `CTRL + ALT + S`
2. Go to Version Control
3. Select the `none` option for the directory

Still Stuck checkout [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aiYMuh7hkdg)