# How to disconnect git for a project in intellij?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

In eclipse, there's just a button disconnect in popup menu selection "team" which can disconnect the project from the version control system like Git or SVN, and even can delete version control information like files in ".git" dir or ".svn" dir of the project.

I can't find the counterpart button in IntelliJ and don't know how to delete the Git information. I deleted the ".git" directory of the project, but opened IntelliJ again, it still show that the project is in Git and can't be pushed to new Git repo.

Comment: This may only be part of it, but delete `.idea/vcs.xml`.

Comment: Remove the project from Git in IntelliJ _first_, and then remove the `.git` directory if it still there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I guess that this could be a duplicate, you can find at least the first part of your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797260/remove-intellij-project-version-control)

After that you remove VCS, you would be able to remove .git directory without any problem

Comment: I think he was able to remove the `.git` directory, but IntelliJ was still showing the project as being tracked by Git.  Your link takes care of the other half of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, it's a good solution. BTW, I can absolutely delete svn information in Eclipse, which means delete the .git directory and all other git info like .gitignore when the version control tool is git. Can I do the same thing in intellij? The answer you suggest just remove the link, and can recover it.

Answer (score 81):

[image: Select the Project and make VCS "None"]

Open the Setting and Click "Version Control then make selected project VCS as None.

Comment: it's no longer there in Idea 2021.3.3.

Comment: It's now under the "Directories" option, one level lower below "Version Control"

Comment: It's now under the "Directory Mappings" option, one level lower below "Version Control"